# Get a list of elements that have attribute names that start with a specific string using XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm trying to get an array of elements that have attribute names that start with "temp" (not the attribute value, or I'd use `querySelectorAll`).

However, it seems that I can't quite get the xpath expression correct. Here is what seems to be the closest I've come up with:

```js
let els = Array.from(document.evaluate(
  `//*/@*[starts-with(name(.), 'temp')]`,
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
  null
).singleNodeValue);

console.log(els);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

I would assume that would give me the 3 divs that contains at least 1 attribute with "temp."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for matching the elements with your XPath while applying the attribute name check as a filtering condition:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]
```

```js
var result = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'temp')]]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var node = result.iterateNext(); 
var nodes = [];
while (node) {
  nodes.push(node);
  node = result.iterateNext();
}
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div temp-callback="1" temp-post-callback="4"></div>
<div temp-callback="2"></div>
<div></div>
<div temp-callback="8" temp-post-callback="7"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, ok. This makes so much more sense. Thank you